# conditional formatting on excel based on the ratio between two columns

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel as shown on the picture below.

I need to apply conditional formatting for column C has a gradient coloration of data bars that reflects the percentage ratio between column B and column C?

Is there any option how to do this?

[image: Excel picture]

Comment: Please show the picture and any attempts you've made

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to program a bit, you can take care of this in Python with Openpyxl.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

gradient = 'FFFFFF'
fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid', start_color=gradient, end_color=gradient)
```

From this point you'll have to create the comparison you want between the two columns so that you can modify the "gradient" variable to the color needed for that cell then use the "fill" to modify the spreadsheet. Dont forget to:

```
wb.save('formatted_workbook.xlsx')
```